# Why do I have more reputation than I thought I did?

Tags: discussion

I have `2,427` reputation right now at SO.  Just this morning I had about `2,2xx` as far as I remember.  Why the sudden jump up?  Does it have anything to do with this?

[image]

Comment: I have a similar question:  why do I have less reputation than I think I should have?

Comment: @James, that _is_ a good question, considering that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers) you blew so far past the rep cap you can no longer see it. (Also, allow me to take this opportunity to say that I love your work. Both that post, and comments you leave even when it's not April 1.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is obviously caused by the unicorn - everyone knows they are magical and can award gifts and benefits.

Comment: Thanks for making me hit my vote limit just to see that unicorn again. :)

Answer (score 6):

You had, 2323 reps [last week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/filter-users/1/Week/2011-03-20/?filter=sudo%20rm&sort=reputationchange&page=1&pagesize=30&_=1301631371062) [Mar 20, 2011 - Mar 26, 2011], according to stackexchange league, so I think its normal.

Comment: So it appears.  I just don't remember having that much. :/